# Monitor displays black screen after start PC

Tags: display, screen, monitor

I have an Ubuntu on ryzen APU system.

Here is the problem: I start my desktop pc and see my monitor is blinking, I tried the monitor on another pc and see the monitor has a problem.

Then I use another monitor for my pc which I know it's working. But when I start the pc, it only shows me the motherboard logo and then black screen. When I expect to see ubuntu login screen.

What could be the issue? I know this second monitor is working, because I tried it on another pc.

Interesting thing is I can see the login screen on my first broken monitor. But I cannot on my second working monitor.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? Has it ever worked? Do you have the right video driver? Question needs more details.

Comment: Yes, I'm using this computer with Ubuntu more than six months without a problem until today. Version is Ubuntu 20

Comment: There is no Ubuntu 20 try again.

Answer (score 0):

Now it's working. I unpluged all the cables and waited a couple of minutes then plugged them again, monitor is displaying normally.
I still have no idea what was the problem but now it's gone. I'm writing this for anyone wonder how the problem has been fixed.